# bootstrap-table - how to ajax back into db?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I've looked all over the interweb and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have loaded a json into an x-editable table as seen here:
http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html

It displays and runs beautifully. But not how do I get that information back into the mysql database everytime a cell is edited?

-thanks in advance,
Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the x-editable instance you can define the **url** parameter, for example:

```
$('#my_table').editable({
    url: 'post.php'
});
```

Then in the post.php you can do with the data what you want. Including updating your MySQL tables.